# invalid column name exception even though when column exists

Tags: c#, sql

when I try to access the database with this query it gives me an error

```
invalid column name 'sandeep' which is the name of the patient ie itemArray[3]
```

code:

```
case "patient":
string queryPatientCheck = @"select * 
                             from patient
                             where 
                             [patientID]={0} and
                             [patientName]={1}";

queryPatientCheck = string.Format(queryPatientCheck, itemArray[2], itemArray[3]);
```

Comment: Try `[patientName]='{1}'` or better yet, use parameters.

Answer (score 3):

well your sql translates to this

```
select * 
                             from patient
                             where 
                             [patientID]={0} and
                             [patientName]=sandeep
```

and in this case it searches for a column called sandeep. What you want is the string sandeep i.e `'sandeep'`

```
select * 
                             from patient
                             where 
                             [patientID]={0} and
                             [patientName]='sandeep'
```